# Both quasiconvex and quasiconcave function

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry

The function $$f(x) = x^2$$ is both quasiconcave and quasiconvex. How can I show this?

Comment: It would be helpful if your question included details of what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @DMcMor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any convex function is quasi-convex. Thus, $f=x^2$ is quasi-convex. Your claim of quasi-concavity is not correct. Function $f$ is quasi-concave if
$$f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda )y)\ge min \{f(x), f(y)\},$$
which is apparently wrong for $f=x^2$.

Comment: Okay  thanks, I think the same as yours. But, I saw this statement in lecture note so I asked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your notes, it probably is $f=x^3$, which is both quasi-concave and quasi-convex.